# scope and global variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I create a array in start of my js,and define button,when click the button a `for` loop must push some element to array,but console log show null at end.
I want get `for` data in global variable and use it every where

```
    var TableName = [];
    $(function(){
        $("#SecondButton").on('click',function(){
            var TableName = [];

            $(".Review").find("input:text").each(function(index,el){
                TableName.push(el.value);
            });
        });
    });
    console.log(TableName);
});
```

Comment: The code above declares **two** variables called "TableName".

Comment: yes i want when user click again on button array fill with new data

Comment: Even if the inner variable wasn't declared, the `console.log` at the end would show an empty array. The `click` event handler is executed *some time in the future* (when a click event occurs) **after** `console.log` was called. If you move `console.log` inside the handler you will get the output you expect.

Comment: to use your array as global simply declare it once in global scope, then just assign value in your function (another declaration with "var" keyword make another variable in the function scope) [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scraaappy/8yhzxmmu/)